# MySQL DELETE statement not deleting rows

Tags: php, mysql

The code below is how I am removing data from my database. The user selects titles he wants to remove and then the query should delete those rows. Unfortunately, that isn't working.

I have made sure the DELETE query works by using it in PhpMyAdmin and MySQL Workbench, but for some reason the PHP code I'm coding is not allowing the deletes to work.

```
<?php
    session_start();
    require ("../login.php");

    if (!isset($_SESSION['user'])) 
        header('Location: ../index.php');

    include ("header.php");
    include ("subnav.php");
?>

    <h2>Current Subscriptions</h2>

    <?php

    $user_id = $_SESSION['user'];

    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        foreach($_POST["titles"] as $title) {
            $stmt = $db->prepare("DELETE FROM subscriptions WHERE user=:user AND title=:title)");
            $stmt->bindValue(':user', $user_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $stmt->bindValue(':title', $title, PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $stmt->execute();
        }
        echo '<p>Thank you! Your changes have been made!</p>';
    }
    else {
        $stmt = $db->prepare
            ("SELECT t.id, t.publisher, t.title
            FROM titles t
                JOIN subscriptions s
                    ON t.id = s.title
            WHERE s.user=:user
            ORDER BY t.id");

        $stmt->bindValue(':user', $user_id, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->execute();
        $rows = $stmt->fetchAll();
        $num_rows = count($rows);
        if ($num_rows == 0)
            echo 'You are not currently subscribed to any titles.';
        else {
            ?>
            <form action="" method="post">
            <?php   
            foreach($rows as $row) 
                echo '<input type="checkbox" name="titles[]" value="' . $row['id'] . '">' . $row['publisher'] . ' - ' . $row['title'] . '<br>';
            ?>
            <input type="submit" value="Update" name ="submit" id="submit">
                </form>
        <?php
        }
    }
    ?>

<?php   
    include ("footer.php");
?>
```

Comment: is there an error-msg? assuming error-reporting is on? do you connect to the db with the same user/privileges as on workbench?

Comment: yes, everything is the same - and im getting no error messages

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do see an extra `)` in your SQL, try removing it.

```
 ("DELETE FROM subscriptions WHERE user=:user AND title=:title)");
```

Comment: <slaps forehead> that was it!

Comment: It happens to all of us. I've spent hours trying to fix something and a bracket, quote, or parentheses were the problem. You get good at spotting them over time.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell with your code, but try wrapping your foreach with

```
try {
    foreach(...) {
        ...
    }
} catch (PDOException $ex) {
    $ex->getMessage();
}
```

This should clearly tell you what's going on.